# How To: Insert into column where the value is on another table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

## ***Summarize the Problem:***

**I want to write a booking code**. I had a little problem, that I wanted to insert a value into the `booked` table that is in another table called `house_info`.

The detail of `booked` & `house_info` database is below:

**Booked Table**

```
 ID_Booking | House_Name | House_ID | House_No | House_Qty | House_Price |
          1 | Rose House |        1 |     RH01 |         1 |             |
          2 | Rose House |        1 |     RH02 |         1 |             |
```

**House Info Table**

```
 House_ID | HouseState_Name | House_Qty | House_Price |
        1 |     Garden City |         8 |        40000|
        2 | Electronic City |        10 |      1000000|
```

I want to insert the `House_Price` value on the `house_info` table into the `House_Price` column on `booked` table every time users input on the **Booking Form**.

## ***Background you've already tried:***

I already tried this using a trigger on `booked` table like below:

**Trigger on Booked Table (Before Insert)**

```
IF NEW.House_ID= '1' THEN SET
NEW.House_Price = 40000;
ELSEIF NEW.House_ID= '2' THEN SET
NEW.House_Price = 1000000;
```

But I realize this is not dynamic because when the company want to change the price of each `HouseState_Name` he needs to change it from the trigger. So I think what I needed is a `query` from `PHP` that can calls the value of each `HouseState_Name` and hold it on an `array` and place it or insert it when the ***Book Query*** passed (I hope my logic is true, I'm sorry if it's false).

I already tried to search too for the `query`'s to use. But I didn't know how am I going to use the query.

## ***Some Codes:***

**Booking.php**

```
require 'Connection.php';

//Check Connection
if ($conn->connect_error){
    die("Connection Failed: ". $conn->connect_error);
}

//Check for Submit
if (filter_has_var(INPUT_POST, 'Submit')) {
    //Get Form Data
    $CustomerEmail= htmlspecialchars($_POST["Email"], ENT_QUOTES);
    $House_Name= htmlspecialchars($_POST["HouseName"], ENT_QUOTES);
    $House_ID = htmlspecialchars($_POST["HouseID "], ENT_QUOTES);
    $House_No = htmlspecialchars($_POST["HouseNo "], ENT_QUOTES);

    //Validate the data fields
    if (!empty($CustomerEmail) && !empty($House_Name)) {
        //Passed
        if (filter_var($CustomerEmail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
            //Failed
            $msg = 'Please use a valid email';
            header("location: ../GardenCity.php?error=PleaseUseValidEmail");
        } else {
            //Passed
            echo "Creating a Booking.<br>";
            //Inserting the Booking Data into Database
            $sql = "INSERT INTO `booked`(`ID_Booking`, `CustomerEmail`, `House_Name`, `House_ID`, `House_No`) 
            VALUES (NULL, '$CustomerEmail', '$House_Name', '$House_ID ', '$House_No', '', '')";
            if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
                header("location: ../GardenCity.php");
            } else {
                echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br><br>" . $conn->error;
            }
        }

    } else {
        header("location: ../GardenCity.php?error=EmptyFields");
    }

}

$conn -> close();
```

## ***Expected Results:***

**Before Update the price**

*Database Looks*

`ID_Booking | House_Name | House_ID | House_No | House_Qty | House_Price |
          1 | Rose House |        1 |     RH01 |         1 |             |
          2 | Rose House |        1 |     RH02 |         1 |             |
          3 | Rose House |        1 |     RH03 |         1 |        40000|`

`House_ID | HouseState_Name | House_Qty | House_Price |
        1 |     Garden City |         7 |        40000|
        2 | Electronic City |        10 |      1000000|`

**After Update the price**

*Database Looks*

`ID_Booking | House_Name | House_ID | House_No | House_Qty | House_Price |
          1 | Rose House |        1 |     RH01 |         1 |             |
          2 | Rose House |        1 |     RH02 |         1 |             |
          3 | Rose House |        1 |     RH03 |         1 |        40000|
          4 | Rose House |        1 |     RH04 |         1 |       200000|`

`House_ID | HouseState_Name | House_Qty | House_Price |
        1 |     Garden City |         6 |       200000|
        2 | Electronic City |        10 |      1000000|`

I hope this is well explained. Please let me know if there's any confusing statements or questions. I will say many thanks to you all if this is answered because I'm so stuck at this and my brain won't work.

Comment: I don't understand what House Name and House No are doing in the booking table !?!?

Comment: looks like you need one to many relationship

Comment: Why would you duplicate informations ? The price can easily be retrieved from `house_info` to `booked` using a `JOIN`. [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)

Comment: @Cid It can't (as presently designed), because the price might change.

Comment: Then why storing the price in `house_info`, instead of using a default value in `booked.House_Price` ?

Comment: It's not really duplicate informations, it's a snapshot of the price at the time of booking

Comment: Also I think your "Before/After Update the price" titles are a bit misleading, It's an `INSERT` you're doing (Well, you're doing an `UPDATE` to the house table followed by an `INSERT` in booked, if I understand it correctly)

Comment: Thank you guys for your clarifications, I appreciate it so much to take you'r time on my question. I'll try to answer all of you: 1.) `House_Name` and `House_No` are on another table (@Strawberry). 2.) It's not duplication informations because the price might change sometimes that's only the habit of the company so we will make it more dynamic to them (@DRY & @Cid). 3.) I still don't know what and how using the default value :) (@Cid). 4.) Sorry if I'm misleading I just want to try describe what it looks like after user input booking form (Pepper).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this could work, basically using a subquery just to fetch the price, that should achieve the same result as your insert trigger, but without using fixed prices.

```
INSERT INTO `booked` (
   `ID_Booking`, 
   `CustomerEmail`,
   `House_Name`, 
   `House_ID`,
   `House_No`, 
   `House_Qty`, 
   `House_Price`
) VALUES (
    NULL, 
   '$CustomerEmail', 
   '$House_Name', 
   '$House_ID',
   '$House_No', 
   '1', 
   (SELECT House_Price FROM house_info WHERE House_ID = '$House_ID')
)
```

**Edit:** I set `House_Qty` at 1, change it according to your needs :)

Maybe you can use the same subquery in your trigger directly instead (haven't tested it) :

```
SET NEW.House_Price = 
   (SELECT House_Price FROM house_info WHERE House_ID = NEW.House_id);
```

Assuming your `House_ID` are unique :)

Comment: Thank you so much for you'r answer I really appreciate it and your trigger is works like a charm, unbelievable why this thing doesn't cross into my mind.

Answer (score 1):

I would expect to see a schema more or less like this:

```
houses(house_id*,name)

house_prices(house_id*,price_start_date*,price)

bookings(booking_id*,customer_id,total)

booking_detail(booking_id*,house_id*,start_date,end_date)

* = (component of) PRIMARY KEY
```

After some reflection, it should be apparent that your present concerns evaporate with this design.

Comment: Thank you so much for you'r answer and you gave me an awesome inspiration to design the database for the future.

Answer (score 0):

You can construct such an `UPDATE` statement with `INNER JOINs` one of which's in the subquery as a `self-JOIN` for `booked` table, put after your existing `INSERT` statement :

```
update house_info h join (
  select b1.House_Price, b2.House_ID
  from booked b1
  join ( select House_ID,max(ID_Booking) as ID_Booking 
                from booked
               group by House_ID
                ) b2
     on b1.House_ID = b2.House_ID and b1.ID_Booking = b2.ID_Booking   
) bb on bb.House_ID = h.House_ID
set h.House_Price = bb.House_Price;
```

but I should admit that your tables' design is not good, because of repeating columns they hold the same information in each.

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=5144be1f731df95cbd368d126a13f443)</kbd>

Comment: Thank you so much for you'r answer I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

```
Insert Into booked_table (ID_Booking, House_Name, House_Id, House_No, House_Qty, House_Price)
Select 1, House_Name, House_ID, 'RHXX', House_Qty, (SELECT House_Price FROM house_info WHERE House_ID = MM1.House_ID) From booked_table MM1
Where
NOT EXISTS(
  SELECT * 
  FROM booked_table MM2
  WHERE MM2.ID_Booking > MM1.ID_Booking
);
```

Fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7Bt3ZTQqbjs1jKzJe34qSF/0

I dont included the increment of the ID_Booking and House_No.
If you want to increase the House_Price, just do that with another query.

Comment: Thank you so much for you'r answer I appreciate it.